# Does php 5.6.6 work with mysql 5.6.23?

Tags: php, mysql, compatibility

Or is php 5.4 only compatible with mysql? I've been having some problems getting my php to work with mysql.

I'm using PHP 5.6.6, Apache 2.4, MySQL 5.6.23. My PHP and Apache work just fine. I created a website using CSV. I wanted to learn how to use MySQL, but I was having problems trying to get MySQL to work with my PHP. Now, I have never take any courses on MySQL nor have I ever used. The only thing I have done with MySQL is install it from the community tab from the MYSQL download page. I followed all the instruction and set my file path to be `C:\mysql`, and my data path to be `C:\mysqldata`, but I don't know, why it doesn't seem to work with my php when I try to connect. Is there another step I have to take to connect? I know a lot of people use `WAMP`, which is something I might look into if I don't get this working, but If there's anyone who has installed all three (`apache` `php` and `mysql`) sperately, know what my problem might be, I'll really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

PDO works on all PHP versions 5.1+, which is the preferred method to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in C:\Apache24\htdocs\CSVUser.php:68 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\CSVUser.php(68): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', 'password') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\CSVUser.php on line 68

Comment: Okay I have handled it, but now this is the only error i get Error!: could not find driver

Comment: @Desamos Check whether the `php_pdo_mysql` extension is loaded.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I honestly wouldn't know how to load that extension. I did check my ext folder in my php folder, and I do in fact see php_pdo_mysql, but I don't know how I would load that. Sorry this is the first time I've tried to setup MySQL with php. Thanks

Comment: If you look in your `php.ini` either in your apache folder or your php folder you should see an `[extension]` or `[extensions]` part. `phpinfo()` will tell you where your `php.ini` is located.